# C when set number to float variable its value changes ( in the precision ) how to keep precise number

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

i have input which is : 602.8235291 
but i noticed that when i do :

```
float x1 = 602.8235291;
printf("%f", x1);
```

The output is : 602.823547 
as you see it is different in the precision .
how can i maintain the same value in x1 ?

Comment: Use a `double` instead.

Comment: @alk Sir, how is that going to affect the default precision of six?

Comment: Adding on to Alk, a `float` only has 23 bits of mantissa for ~7 decimal digits of precision

Comment: @alk It will *reduce* the effect, but won't eliminate it..

Comment: ... and put an F at the end of your constant litteral : 602.8235291F

Comment: Short answer: You can't with the standard floating-point representation.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The question is "*How can i maintain the same value **in** `x1`*" ;-)

Comment: @clarasoft-it: Aren't floating point literals `double` by default?

Comment: @alk yes, you are right. So adding the F will not work, my mistake

Comment: There are infinite number of of numbers.  There are typically about 2**32 different exactly representable `float` values.  `602.823_5291` is not one of them - so code cannot maintain that _same exact_ value.   `602.823_54736328125` is the closest one.  `602.823_48632812` is the next closest one.  Expect `float` to maintain `FLT_DIG` (e.g. 6) significant digits as in `602.823`.